# invalid byte sequence in CP950 issue on Windows 7

Tags: vagrant

My O\S is windows 7 64bit, when I typing `vagrant box list` the message comes out

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:176:in `downcase': invalid byte sequence in CP950 (ArgumentError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in fs_real_path'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:175:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:175:in `block in fs_real_path'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:174:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:174:in `fs_real_path'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:121:in `initialize'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/bin/vagrant:180:in `new'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/bin/vagrant:180:in `<main>'
```

I used vagrant for a long time, it occurs when I update vagrant to 1.8.7, but even when I downgrade to 1.8.6 the problem still there, and I tried to uninstall and reinstall vagrant and VirtualBox both but still the same, have no idea what happened.

Comment: can you try to add `# encoding: utf-8` on top of your Vagrantfile ?

Comment: I guess it's nothing to do with Vagrantfile, because vagrant box list is a global command

Comment: ok I misread and thought it was against a particular vagrantfile - the issue has to do with ruby and encoding